# Have there ever been any schemes for the classification of experiments?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, science

There have been several *book* classification schemes, for example: Dewey Decimal, Library of Congress, etc. Have there been any *experiment* classification schemes, *i.e.* sets of criteria by which to classify (say) Eratosthenes' experiment for the measurement of the earth, or Fletcher's experiment for the measurement of the electric charge of the electron?

I suppose that Mill's methods of induction (1843) implicitly categorize many experiments, but is this the best we've got?

Comment: To what end? Define the purpose of such a scheme.

Comment: @JonCuster I'm not sure whether such a scheme would serve a purpose. I suspect that that would be easier to determine after review of the attempts. But conjecturally: one purpose could be to group related experiments together both as an aid to the memory and to facilitate both learning and developing the scientific method. But need everything have a purpose? What is the purpose of thinking about irrational numbers? They can all be approximated by rational numbers as closely as one pleases. I think that the categorization of experiments is itself of interest.

Comment: How do you feel about the Physics Subject Headings from the American Physical Society (https://physh.org/)? Is that a classification scheme?

Comment: @JonCuster Fascinating! Surely it is a classification scheme, or even several bundled together. The list of Experimental Techniques (at https://physh.org/browse?disciplines=&facet=fa2a6718-de5c-4c05-bf00-f169a55234d5) comes pretty close to what I was looking for, albeit it only covers physics.

Comment: @JonCuster is there such an organised database for physical experiments? just as an example, if I wanted to find the most modern implementations of the cavendish experiment, where should I look etc.

Comment: @JonCuster Yes but even the APS missed at least one other stratifying class, theoretical vs applied physics.